# How do I progress past the initial tier of gear/crafting in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I've been playing Terraria for a few hours.  I've got the basics understood - I've built houses for NPCs, explored, mined resources, etc.

At this point I've got a gold Broadsword and some Copper armor.  I keep reading about cool stuff on the Terraria wiki, but nearly all of it comes with caveats like "you'd better have a full set of <ridiculous armor> before you try this!"

My question is: what do I do now?  I can mine more gold/silver/iron, but that won't improve my gear by much.  I'd like to find a Floating Island, but I have no easy way to fly or find them short of using a mapping tool. I'd like to check out the Dungeon in my world, but there's no way I'll be able to defeat its boss with my current gear.

I'm just not sure what exactly my next move(s) should be to progress and get my character to the point where I **can** explore these advanced areas.

Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the progression route in Terraria?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24950/what-is-the-progression-route-in-terraria)

Comment: @MageXy The linked question was asked later than this one.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf [Duplicates are not always determined chronologically.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651) I thought the other question (which also incidentally has more upvotes) had better quality answers, so I flagged this one as the dupe.

Comment: A question having more quality answers isn't grounds for duping, but you guys do what you will, I'll abstain from this one.

Comment: They are not duplicates, just very similar; this one is early game, that one is mid game. -- Both contain useful info.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can go exploring some [corrupted](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Corruption)/[crimson](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Crimson) areas (randomly picked at world generation) to destroy the [shadow orbs](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Orb)/[crimson heart](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_Heart) waiting for you at the bottom of chasms.

Each shadow orb/crimson heart destroyed will provide you some loot, and make a [meteorite](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteorite_%28biome%29) land on the world. Once the meteorite has fallen, go find the site, and mine the meteorite ore. This will allow you to craft some meteorite gear and weapons.

Once you've destroyed three shadow orbs/crimson heart, it will make the [Eater of Worlds](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eater_of_Worlds)/[Brain of Cthulhu](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Brain_of_Cthulhu) spawn, allowing you to fight two different bosses.

Note: The shadow orbs are protected behind some [ebonstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ebonstone)/[crimstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimstone_Block), which you will not be able to mine with your current pickaxe. Just buy some dynamite from the [Demolitionist](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demolitionist) and use it to access the shadow orb. Or you can buy [purification powder](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/purification_powder) from the [Dryad](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dryad), which turns the ebonstone/crimstone into the easily destroyable standard stone.

Comment: +1 as Nightmare/Shadow gear should be the next 'oomph' needed to open up the next areas of the game and is achievable with gold/silver gear.

Comment: Also, it's not required, but definitely handy to have a Grappling Hook (http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Grappling_Hook) as well as the Silver/Gold armor for going into the chasms where the Shadow Orbs are in the Corruption

Comment: This was exactly the advice I needed... now I'm decked out in Shadow/Meteor gear, swingin' a Phaseblade, killin' Skeletron!

Comment: note that with the latest update you can only use bomb to go through ebonstone.

Comment: You may also want to see if you can find a Jungle Binome.  If you can, and you feel a little bit brave, harvest some jungle material, as it will greatly help in fighting Eater of Worlds. More than likely though, you WILL have to take on Eater of Worlds with just chest-found items and gold gear...you could also go delving a bit more and open a few more chests if you're feeling like you haven't got good enough weaponry.  But your next material upgrade will definitely be Nightmare/Shadow gear.

Answer (score 10):

You can take on the [Eye of Cthulu](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eye_of_Cthulu) with a bow and a pile of potions. Farm lenses from the [Demon Eyes](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Eye) at night.  With 6 lenses at an [Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Altar), you can craft a [Suspicious Looking Eye](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Suspicious_Looking_Eye) to summon the Eye of Cthulhu. Be sure to use the eye at night or the summon won't work.

Once defeated, use the demonite/crimtane ore dropped to craft a [Nightmare](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nightmare_Pickaxe)/[Deathbringer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Deathbringer_Pickaxe) Pickaxe which you can use to get [hellstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellstone) and [obsidian](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Obsidian) to make hellstone bars.  Hellstone bars are used to make the highest pre-hardmode gear.

Comment: Hellstone gear is currently bugged (1.0.2) and is not considered as useful as Cobalt/Necro armor since its set bonus is not applied. Also, jumping straight down to the hell level is not likely to be any more of ease then trying to take out Skeletron in his current gear.

Comment: I was unaware of the Hellstone bug.  However, it's likely to be fixed in the near future.  While swinging the demonite pick you rarely, if ever, get hit with fire balls from imps.  Worms pose the only threat and spawn rarely.

Comment: Actually, this is a little misleading. The Nightmare Pickaxe requires Shadow Scales as well, which are only found by defeating the eater of worlds. You can summon him by smashing shadow orbs.

Answer (score 4):

If you can get past the Eye Of Cthulhu, the dryad will show up. She will sell you purification dust which will let you convert ebonstone to regular stone and allow you to get to those tasty shadow orbs.

Comment: Every time I start a new character, I forget to do this and spend my money on dynamite instead.  Using powder is slower, but **much** less expensive!

Comment: bombs are quite common, i never have trouble destroying the orbs using bombs

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is start breaking shadow orbs.  I am still not tough / skilled enough to defeat the eye of Cthulhu on my own, but by breaking the third shadow orb, you can spawn the Eater of Worlds.

Although difficult, and although it will take some time, the Eater of Worlds will not de-spawn (like the eye will) once you die.  It will also track you down to where you are, so with some patience, and many deaths, you can kill it, yielding a piece of shadow armour and some deamonite to help build the nightmare pickaxe to mine out that meteor which will eventually fall.

Answer (score 1):

A tip is to kill eater of worlds for shadow scales and demonite. Then make a nightmare pickaxe and mine 20 obsidian to make an obsidian skull.

With these two items you can then mine meteorite and hellstone safely without burn damage. I suggest harvesting eater of worlds after that, selling his demonite ore, and buying a minishark + ammo. Then use the meteor to make meteor shots. Then you can kill skeletron. For the dungeon I would advise making a fiery greatsword.

Answer (score 0):

Bombs are pretty common if you farm cave chests, so do that and use them to break the ebonstone maybe

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get molten armor (found in the nether deep underground) and good weapons.  Crimson or corrupted armor is a good suggestion. Find it in rare chests or craft it from lens from eyes and craft with a demon altar. If your talking about hard mode bosses, (destroyer, The Twins, Etc) then you'll need to unlock hard mode by killing the wall of flesh. Crimson recommended with the minishark. The game seems Incapable for more powerful items, but they are hidden in many places. Happy Killing!

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you should do is the eater of worlds.the first thing you do is farm the corrupt bio me monsters and they will drop rotten chunks now you will need 15 of those and 20  vile powder to get vile powder you will need to get the mushrooms from the corrupt biome now once you have the the ingredients go to a demon alter and craft worm food and that will summon the eater of words once you defeat it you will get allot of important things that you will need to progress in the game.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest after you kill skeleton keep making new worlds and find out if one or more have Crimson biome and delete the corruption ones
So you have access to crimtane stuff and tell me if you need more stuff
Said

Answer (score -1):

The thing i would suggest to get pretty good armor is to beat the Wall Of Flesh. Doing so will convert your game to hardmode and add tons of other things in the game. To beat the Wall of Flesh, I used just the minishark, full molten armor, and one healing potion. it took me three tries but i finally did it.
Something else i would recommend is to make an imp staff. The imp Staff is something created with 17 hellstone bars, that summons a little flying imp to fight with you. It doesn't do *that* much damage, but it certainly helps.
once you Beat the Wall of Flesh, you will get a Pwnhammer, which is strong enough to destroy Demon/Crimson Altars. Every time you destroy a Demon/Crimson altar, it will add Cobalt/Mythril/Titanium/adamantite ore to your world, which is used to make some of the hardmode armor sets.
Next you should get wings. to get Demon or Angel wings,  you will need:
Angel Wings: 20 feathers, 25 souls of light, and 20 souls of flight.
Demon Wings: same as angel wings, except use souls of night instead of souls of light
to find out how to get souls, look on YouTube

Answer (score -3):

To find floating islands, you need to take a *Gravitatie potion*, go to the heights where the floating islands are, and turn your word around every second while you move. This way you don't need wings.

Another way is to build a sky bridge.

Comment: @Timelord64 I don't know why this would be considered "Not an answer". It's not a complete answer, yes, but an answer nevertheless. `I'd like to find a Floating Island, but I have no easy way to fly or find them short of using a mapping tool.` This Post gives 2 ways how to.

Comment: Actually, the question is `How do I progress past the initial tier of gear/crafting in Terraria?` not `How do I get to a Floating Island?`