# I defeated all mechanical bosses, what do I do next?

Tags: terraria

So, Im playing Terraria, I recently defeated all mechanical bosses: The Destroyer, The Twins and Skeletron Prime. Ive gone to the jungle and got myself a full set of Chlorophyte and Im confused. What do I do next? (Im on PC by the way)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What is the progression route in Terraria?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/24950/143571)

Comment: The next boss in the progression is Plantera, but apart from bossing you can also now craft the Mechanical Cart, as well as explore any or all of the things on this list: https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Mechanical_bosses. The Steampunker starts selling teleporters after the first mechanical boss, so one thing I like to do is start to build a portal network, although this became less imperative after the introduction of Pylons.

Answer (score 0):

One of the next bosses that you should go for is Plantera.

In the underground jungle, you'll occasionally see a flower-like bulb growing on the jungle grass, and when you break the bulb Plantera will be summoned.

I'd recommend not leaving the underground jungle during a Plantera fight, because once it's outside of the jungle, or on the world's surface then it'll become enraged and be much more dangerous.

Comment: Thank you for the help! What equipment do you suggest for Plantera? I have found a Plantera Bulb already while trying to find chlorophyte.

Comment: I personally cannot say unfortunately, as I myself am most comfortable with only playing in Pre-Hardmode (I'm strange like that), but there are some pretty decent Plantera guides on YouTube to watch that could explain the boss fight and it's needed preparation much better than I could.  I could link a decent guide video that I've found if you're interested.